# How to work with date and time in KDB

Tags: kdb

I tried to work with `dateDtimespan` type by subtracting one `dateDtimespan` from another, but KDB (QPad) always shows 0 as a result, why?

Also if I have, say, `datetime 12.11.2014:22:33:00.000000000`   in one column and only time `22:32:00.000000000`    in another, how I may remove date part from the first column to subtract time portion from the second column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to remove the date, you can use the cast operator, **$**. To reference only the time, you can prefix $ with `time as shown below.

```
q).z.z
2015.02.23T14:10:33.523

q)`time$.z.z
14:10:30.731

q)t:([]ts:10#.z.N;ti:.z.t-til 10)

q)exec `time$ts-ti from t

00:00:00.000 00:00:00.001 00:00:00.002 00:00:00.003 00:00:00.004 00:00:00.005..
```

You can see more examples here. http://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#cast

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefer downcasting the `timestamp` to `timespan` first and then calculate the diff i.e. `` (`timespan$p)-n ``. No harm in using the other way (`` `timespan$p-n ``) but it is less explicit than the former.

```
q)dt:( [] p:2#2014.12.11D22:33:00.000000000;n:2#22:32:00.000000000)
q)select (`timespan$p)-n from dt
p
--------------------
0D00:01:00.000000000
0D00:01:00.000000000
```